# Why am I getting NameError: Not Defined after adding to urls.py?

Tags: django-urls

I am getting this error:

```
NameError at /storefront/
name 'storefront' is not defined
```

My Urls.Py looks like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from accounts.views import home
from django.contrib import admin   

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r"^$", home),
url(r"^storefront/", storefront, name="storefront")
```

My Views.Py looks like this:

```
def storefront(request):
    latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter()
    context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}
    return render(request, 'storefront.html', context)
```

Is the error in the urls or the views?

Comment: Well, the error is clear, the object *storefront* you reference inside your url route is not imported anywhere. I am unsure as to how your application is structured module wise, but maybe you forgot to import your storefront function in your urls.py?

Comment: You were right, I forgot to import it.  It's working now.